# Passing trough arguments for a function as Selector for a scheduledTimer

Tags: ios, swift, timer, selector, nstimer

So I start a scheduled timer when pressing a button (in a function)

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: Selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I want to passthrough an argument data for update in the selector, because I need the the data,  but it's only available in the function, but I can't declare the function in this function and use it as #selector.

so ideally:

```
func update(data: CMMotionActivity) { some code here }
```

and in the timer than as the selector not ViewController.update, but somewhat like ViewController.update(data: myAwesomeArray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use userInfo

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: Selector(ViewController.update(_:)), userInfo: ["data" : youData], repeats: true)
```

And get it in your function:

```
func update(data: Timer) {
   let userInfo = timer.userInfo as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
   let data = userInfo["data"]
   //use your data
}
```

Comment: if it helps you solving your problem just don't forget to accept the answer ;-)